# How to use GL_POINTS and MSAA in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, pyglet

I'm a Newbie in OpenGl. I try to draw points with Pyglet. But if I change the configs of the window, to enable MSAA, the points disappear. For other primitives this is not the case. I think this is a OpenGL problem and not caused by Pyglet.
My goal is to use MSAA (for getting smooth lines) or config2 in example code and also see the points.

Please see the example code and switch between the different configs.

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

config1 = Config(sample_buffers=1, samples=4)
config2 = Config(sample_buffers=1, samples=4, double_buffer=True)

window = pyglet.window.Window()                         # everything there, but no smooth line
# window = pyglet.window.Window(config = config1)       # draws nothing
# window = pyglet.window.Window(config = config2)       # draws only smooth line, points missing

batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

line = batch.add(2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES, None, ('v2f', (270, 165, 370, 315)))
point = batch.add(2, pyglet.gl.GL_POINTS, None, ('v2f', (300, 165, 400, 315)))

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    batch.draw()
    
pyglet.app.run()
```

It's a problem with MSAA but I don't really understand why my Points disappear. Any fixes/explanations?

Comment: MSAA takes an average of multiple samples in the pixel to smooth and make it more or less dim depending on how much of the shape is inside the pixel. If the shape in the pixel is literally just a point, then all samples will not hit it and make the pixel pretty much the same color as the background. Try making the point bigger ([glPointSize](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPointSize.xml)).

Comment: @TedKleinBergman thanks for your answer! With glPointSize it worked - but not as intended. But I think the error is on my side. How you've said you can't draw something smooth if it is just a single point. By playing around with the point size it helped me a lot to understand MSAA. Thanks!